# Implement drag and drop option on existing datagrid rows?

Tags: c#, jquery

I have an events datagrid with data sorted by event order(have a column called event_order in database table). I need to implement drag and drop option so that user can drag any row and drop any where between the rows so that ajax should update my database table to with that updated order of the item. Just suggest me how to start on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into JQueryUI plugin.  It has drag AND drop:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/